# Intuition on simple linear regression signal plus noise model

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, heterogeneity

I'm currently studying linear regression on this book 
"F.M. Dekking - A Modern Introduction to Probability and Statistics: Understanding Why and How" where the signal+noise model is presented:

$Y_i = \alpha\ + \beta x_i\ + U_i$

where $x_i$ are non-random, $U_i$ are independent r.v.s with $E[U_i] = 0$ and $Var(U_i) = \sigma^2$ and $Y_i$ are, therefore, independent r.v.s with $E[Y_i] = \alpha\ + \beta x_i$ and $Var(Y_i) = \sigma^2$

He writes that "*$\{Y_1, ..., Y_n \}$ do not form a random sample because given that each $Y_i$ have different expectation, they have different distributions*" and he writes also that "*if we assume that $U_i$ are normally distributed we can use MLE to estimate $\alpha,\beta$*".

Now, given this two facts, how could we use MLE on something that is not a sample? Maybe the correct interpretation is that $\{Y_1, ..., Y_n \}$ is i.n.i.d. sample, but, if it is the case, would it be ok to use MLE?

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246047/independent-variable-random-variable

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tim. I've read it all but it seems to me that actually it is mainly concerned with the random vs. fixed nature of the $X_i$ variables - anyway, the best answer is really "not for everybody" as someone wrote.
What I don't understand here is the "$Y_i$ do not form a random sample" thing... did you intend that in that link there are some hints (that I therefore do not see) to cope with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the related question asking about [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259704/is-there-i-i-d-assumption-on-logistic-regression/259757#259757). The quotes you posted sound confusing, but what they are saying is that $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ are independent, but not identically distributed, since they have different means

$$
Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma^2)
$$

where $\mu_i$ is defined in terms of functional relationship $\mu_i = \alpha + \beta X_i$, what is equivalent of saying that

$$
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_i &\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) \\
Y_i &= \alpha + \beta X_i + \varepsilon_i
\end{align}
$$

so $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ *are* random samples, but they are not i.i.d. Since they are random variables, we can define a likelihood function for the model describing their *joint distribution*

$$
L(\alpha,\beta,\sigma^2 \mid Y) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(y_i; \alpha + \beta x_i, \; \sigma^2)
$$

so we can estimate the parameters based on it (using [MLE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms), or [Bayesian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252577/bayes-regression-how-is-it-done-in-comparison-to-standard-regression/252608#252608) estimation). You can also check the [answers and comments in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303742/normal-regression-model/303768#303768) for extended discussion and [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246047/independent-variable-random-variable) for more formal discussion of somehow similar question.

Comment: Ok, so the sample is i.n.i.d. and I can use MLE to estimate the parameters