# What is the best syllabus for an under-grad class in Statistics for engineer students?

Tags: references, teaching, engineering-statistics

I teach statistics to under-grad engineer students who major in Information Technology (IT). My students first learn a (prerequisite) course on probability where they learn combinatorics, different probability distributions and the central limit theorem. Currently I teach a pretty traditional syllabus: point estimation, confidence intervals, hypothesis testing and simple linear regression (the syllabus is correlated with chapters 7-11 in Montgomery and Rumer's [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118539710)).

I have added some examples in R to the lessons, but that is the only change I've performed so far.

I'm wondering if and how I can update the course. This is actually a follow up question on my previous question as to [why does hypothesis testing focus on the mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306827/why-does-basic-hypothesis-testing-focus-on-the-mean-and-not-on-the-median).

Specifically, I'm wondering **what are the most valuable practices that I can teach my students**, and **if there are different (and better, more dated) syllabuses** out there which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You could start looking at what offerings there are, for instance mooc's [here](https://www.google.no/search?q=engineering+statistics+mooc&oq=engineering+statistics+mooc&aqs=chrome..69i57.3536j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  and [more traditional courses](https://www.google.no/search?q=syllabus+for+introductory+engineering+statistics&oq=syllabus+for+introductory+engineering+statistics+&aqs=chrome..69i57.17132j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  Hopefully some other can answer based on actual experience.

Some general ideas: [statistics 21 century](http://statsthinking21.org/),  [some discussion papers](https://www.google.no/search?safe=off&ei=bnA0Xd_nOIixrgTszKSwBQ&q=statistics+curriculum+for+the+21st+century&oq=statistics+curriculum+for+the+21st+century&gs_l=psy-ab.3...25373.30957..32268...0.0..0.163.1214.16j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i304i39j0i8i7i30j0i7i30j0i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i30j33i10.lGJGAR3nH0I&ved=0ahUKEwjf1uLElsbjAhWImIsKHWwmCVYQ4dUDCAo&uact=5).

Comment: thanks for resurfacing this question. I've forgotten I've posted it.. I know to google of course, but everything seems the same, even if the authors claim it is for the 21st century. The only thing I found that is sort of what I'm looking for, is a 2007 paper by George Webb, which states that statistics should be taught differently: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/6hb3k0nz

Comment: That's George Cobb.